# QGIS doesn't recognize numeric cell content (xls)

Tags: qgis, csv, excel, string

I want to join Excel data (numeric) to a Shapefile in QGIS. Although the cells are defined as numbers in Excel, QGIS recognizes them as string. I tried also csv, csv (windows), txt, xls, xlsx, none of them worked out.

I remember 3 years ago I used a csvt-file in order to help QGIS to recognize the data. But aI also remember that I could join Excel sheet content as numbers 6 months ago without creating a csvt file...

Comment: Have you checked/sanitized the field? Meaning is it possible somewhere in that column there is a non-numeric character or null that might be preventing it from being recognized as numeric? Is the field header valid?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem:
Try to import it as csv and then via MMQGIS plugin -> Modify -> Text to Float

Comment: Thanks. I tried MMQGIS. I could change change the type of one coloumn from string to real. But when I try to join the data to the shapefile, all the columns (string, real) are NULL...

Comment: do saved the data as e.g. shape before the join?